# Use same menu on all pages with different templates in joomla

Tags: joomla

I am new to joomla. I am trying to use same menu for all page with using different templates for pages.
In menu list for hoempage menu item I am using template1 which is ok. I want same menu layout for other pages but with different template. How can be achieve that. But without using same template, Only need is to be same menu layout but other design should be different as per selected template.
Using Menu Jf and superfish menu.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your default template may be assigned for same menu item. Check it and try to remove this assignment. Go to protostar template and check assignment of menu items if it is assigned to same menu items remove that assignment.